# How do we prove the metrics $d_{j}:\textbf{R}^{n}\times\textbf{R}^{n}\to\textbf{R}_{\geq0}$ are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, equivalent-metrics

Given two points $x,y\in\textbf{R}^{n}$, prove the following inequalities
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(x,y) \leq d_{1}(x,y) \leq \sqrt{n}d_{2}(x,y)
\end{align*}

**MY ATTEMPT**

According to its corresponding definitions, we have

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
d_{1}(x,y) = |x_{1} - y_{1}| + |x_{2} - y_{2}| + \ldots + |x_{n} - y_{n}|\\\\
d_{2}(x,y) = (|x_{1} - y_{1}|^{2} + |x_{2} - y_{2}|^{2} + \ldots + |x_{n} - y_{n}|^{2})^{1/2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
d^{2}_{1}(x,y) - d^{2}_{2}(x,y) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}|x_{i} - y_{i}|\sum_{j\neq i}|x_{j} - y_{j}|  \geq 0 \Rightarrow d_{1}(x,y)\geq d_{2}(x,y)
\end{align*}

Similarly, we have that
\begin{align*}
nd^{2}_{2}(x,y) - d^{2}_{1}(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(n-1)|x_{k} - y_{k}|^{2} - \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}-y_{i}|\sum_{j\neq i}|x_{j} - y_{j}|
\end{align*}
then I get stuck.

Can someone please help me finishing this exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}$
For the right inequality, we can apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
d_1(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - y_i| \leq \bb{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - y_i|^2}^\frac{1}{2}\bb{\sum_{i=1}^n 1}^\frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{n}d_2(x,y)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Right to the point (+1)